# UIWebView showing error while executing JavaScript in iOS

Tags: ios, sdk, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView where some javascript is also being executed. When we click on the first button it properly executes the javascript code and works perfectly, however when we click on any other button and then navigate back to old view, javascript didn't work. Below is my code.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView { 
    NSMutableString *javascriptFunctions = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"var t3 = new function() { this.setTitle = function(text) { window.location.href = 'about:title:' + encodeURIComponent(text); }; "];
    [javascriptFunctions appendString:@"this.setAppointment = function(beginTime, endTime, title, description, isUTC) { window.location.href = 't3://web-command/calendar?beginTime=' + encodeURIComponent(beginTime) + '&endTime=' + encodeURIComponent(endTime) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title) + '&description=' + encodeURIComponent(description) + '&isUTC=' + encodeURIComponent(isUTC); }; "];
    [javascriptFunctions appendString:@"this.setBackButtonVisibility = function(isVisible) { window.location.href = 'about:back:' + encodeURIComponent(isVisible); }; "];
    [javascriptFunctions appendString:@"this.getBack = function() { window.history.back(); }; "];
    [javascriptFunctions appendString:@"this.close = function() { window.location.href = 'about:close'; }; }"];

    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptFunctions];
}


- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)currentWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([[request.URL.scheme lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"tel"]) {
        return YES;
    }

    NSString* url = [request.URL.absoluteString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    if (url == nil) {
        [self backToMainScreen];
    return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript function will not invoke until web page is completely loaded on UIWebView. So called your all javascript function inside delegate method webViewDidFinishLoad.

```
 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSMutableString *javascriptFunctions = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"var t3 = new function() { this.setTitle = function(text) { window.location.href = 'about:title:' + encodeURIComponent(text); }; "];
    [javascriptFunctions appendString:@"this.setAppointment = function(beginTime, endTime, title, description, isUTC) { window.location.href = 't3://web-command/calendar?beginTime=' + encodeURIComponent(beginTime) + '&endTime=' + encodeURIComponent(endTime) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title) + '&description=' + encodeURIComponent(description) + '&isUTC=' + encodeURIComponent(isUTC); }; "];
    [javascriptFunctions appendString:@"this.setBackButtonVisibility = function(isVisible) { window.location.href = 'about:back:' + encodeURIComponent(isVisible); }; "];
    [javascriptFunctions appendString:@"this.getBack = function() { window.history.back(); }; "];
    [javascriptFunctions appendString:@"this.close = function() { window.location.href = 'about:close'; }; }"];

    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptFunctions];



   }
```